# How to send stdout of a process over HTTP

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, http, stdout

I have an endpoint setup in my MVC app that kicks off a external process (powershell script). I'd like to be able to redirect the output to the browser "live" as it is created. Are there any examples of how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide more information about what you are doing?  It sounds like you have an MVC application that is running like a service which is launching other processes and you are wanting to be able to see the output of these other processes in another application, a web browser.  Why not display the output in the MVC application?

Comment: It's really just an API endpoint that kicks off a service remotely and I want to be able to display the output to the remote machine calling the endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the process' standard output stream and feeding it via [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/) to the browser should work. Here you can find [some examples](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Hubs) to help you get started with SignalR.

This might also be useful to you if you decide to give it a try:

[Broadcasting over a Hub from outside of a Hub](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs) (at the bottom of the page)

I use SignalR myself successfully in a similar scenario (feeding a real-time progress of a long-running operation to the browser).

Answer (score 0):

An approach you may consider is one that I used in a small point of sale application to allow remote queries through a web browser.

I created a simple web server that ran in its own thread as a DLL that was attached to the rest of the application.  When the application started up, it would check to see if the web server should be started as well.

This was a very simple web server using C++ and CAsynch sockets however what it allowed was to use a web browser from some other computer to do two kinds of access: (1) pull down files such as HTML pages, Javascript, images, etc. like a normal web server and (2) activate specific functional components with a function specific URL such as to generate a report.

Using this I was also successful using JavaScript with JSON as well.

There are a number of places you can find the source code samples for a simple HTTP web server in a variety of languages and there are some examples and links within stackoverflow questions.

The key to this is to have your web server functionality implement the HTTP protocol and to maintain the TCP connection pushing additional content out.  The additional content in your case would be the output from the process which you have launched.

So this will require you to launch the process and do the standard I/O redirect so that the process you launch will send its output through a pipe to your web server which will then read the process output from the pipe and then send it out the open TCP port to the browser.

Using this you could actually do some JavaScript to have the browser user send commands back to the process being run by developing a text based protocol that is sent back to the web server which then sends the incoming text out to the launched process.

Some of this is actually similar to the older CGI type of functionality used in the original web servers before Apache, etc.  What these servers did was to launch an application, usually some script such as Perl though also sometimes something compiled such as C, and then take the standard output from the application and just reflect it back to the browser TCP connection.  Common Gateway Interface, I think is what it means.